# js count coming up as Nan within html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a issue where any of the `+ count +` in this part of my js, Are all coming back as `Nan` outside of the first one, which is this one `<th scope="row" class="product-id">' + count + '</th>`

```js
var count = 1;

function new_link() {
  count++;
  var e = document.createElement("tr");
  e.id = count, e.className = "product";
  var t = '<tr><th scope="row" class="product-id">' + count + '</th><td class="text-start"><div class="mb-2"><input class="form-control bg-light border-0" type="text" name="productName-' + count + '" id="productName-' + count + '" placeholder="Product Name"></div><textarea class="form-control bg-light border-0" id="productDetails-' + count + '" rows="2" placeholder="Product Details"></textarea></div></td><td><input class="form-control bg-light border-0 product-price" type="number" id="productRate-' + count + '" step="0.01" placeholder="$0.00"></td><td><div class="input-step"><button type="button" class="minus">–</button><input type="number" class="product-quantity" id="product-qty-' + count + '" value="0" readonly><button type="button" class="plus">+</button></div></td><td class="text-end"><div><input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 product-line-price" id="productPrice-' + count + '" value="$0.00" placeholder="$0.00" /></div></td><td class="product-removal"><a class="btn btn-success">Delete</a></td></tr>';
}
```

I need all `+ counts +` to give a numerical value so i can `$_POST` them later. Most are within html elements. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Your code appears to be neither complete (You never call `new_link` nor inspect its output), nor minimal (you generate a massive string of HTML that can surely be reduced to a single element), nor is formatted in a readable format (new lines are not a sin).

Comment: `NaN` is produced when a string is converted to a Number, but that string does not contain a parseable number. Check for this.

Comment: It looks fine to me, other than starting your count at 1 and immediately incrementing it (meaning your first function call will use count equal to 2). See @gyoheon-lee's answer for a runnable version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution!

I also change var to const and apostrophe(') to backtick(`)!

```js
let count = 1;

function new_link() {
    count++;
    const e = document.createElement("tr");
    e.id = count;
    e.className = "product";
    const t = `
        <th scope="row" class="product-id">${count}</th>
        <td class="text-start">
            <div class="mb-2">
                <input class="form-control bg-light border-0" type="text" name="productName-${count}" id="productName-${count}" placeholder="Product Name" />
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control bg-light border-0" id="productDetails-${count}" rows="2" placeholder="Product Details"></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control bg-light border-0 product-price" type="number" id="productRate-${count}" step="0.01" placeholder="$0.00">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-step">
                <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
                <input type="number" class="product-quantity" id="product-qty-${count}" value="0" readonly />
                <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-end">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 product-line-price" id="productPrice-${count}" value="$0.00" placeholder="$0.00" />
        </div>
        </td>
        <td class="product-removal">
            <a class="btn btn-success">Delete</a>
        </td>
    `;
    e.innerHTML = t;
    return e;
}

console.log(new_link());
console.log(new_link());
console.log(new_link());
```